# Prism 7 UWP Navigation Back Parameters Missing

Tags: uwp, prism, prism-7

Given A Prism 7 UWP Application with three Views and corresponding ViewModels:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<BlankPage1, BlankPage1ViewModel>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<BlankPage2, BlankPage2ViewModel>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<BlankPage3, BlankPage3ViewModel>();
```

If we navigate from BlankPage1 to BlankPage2 passing a parameter (from within a Command in ViewModel1):

```
public virtual DelegateCommand GoToPage2Command => new DelegateCommand(GoToPage2);
public virtual async void GoToPage2() {
     await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("BlankPage2", null, ("param", 5678));
}
```

In the `OnNavigatedToAsync` override of `BlankPage2ViewModel` the parameter is correctly passed in.

Now if we navigate from `BlankPage2ViewModel` to `BlankPage3ViewModel`, via a Command and pass another Parameter

```
public virtual DelegateCommand GoToPage3Command => new DelegateCommand(GoToPage3);
public virtual async void GoToPage3() {
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("BlankPage3", null, ("param", 1234));
}
```

Again this works and the parameter value `1234` is passed to `BlankPage3ViewModel`.

Now however if we navigate back to `BlankPage2ViewModel`:

`await NavigationService.GoBackAsync();`

No parameters are passed back into the `OnNavigatedToAsync` override of `BlankPage2ViewModel`. Surely we would expect to see the parameter value `5678`?

**NOTE**: We also set `NavigationCacheMode` to `Required` inside each view.

An answer to a [question asked over on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4d0be96-6810-470d-9024-17e092ccdf9b/uwpuwp-navigate-to-the-same-frame?forum=wpdevelop), regarding a similar issue states:

> If you use Frame.Navigate to navigate to the same page, your PageA won't be reinstanciated but the OnNavigatedTo method will be called with the new parameters.
>
> That way, you can change the information displayed on the page (even play some transition if needed); and **as an added bonus the Frame history does keep your previous PageA parameters, allowing you to call Frame.GoBack to return to the previous PageA state**.

Is this by design in Prism that no parameters are passed back or a potential bug?

Comment: I created a simple UWP project to test, it does work.

Comment: @Bite I have done the same, it does work with a UWP app. It also worked in Template10's NavigationService, unfortunately this is either an issue with Prism or a feature not implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bite said, there's no problem in the general UWP project. When you call `Frame.Navigate(typeof(page), "params");` method to navigate between the different pages and call `Frame.GoBack()` method to go back to the previous page, the parameters will be still there.

Since you're using the Prism's navigation service, there should be some different places in it. If you want to know the detailed reason, you need to debug its [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Source) source code to know about the principle of its navigation service.

Here, I'm also interested in its navigation service, so I spent some time to study on its source code. The core of navigation services should be in the [NavigationService.cs](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/Navigation/NavigationService.cs) and [FrameFacade.cs](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/Navigation/FrameFacade.cs).

You could see that it finally will call the [_frame.Navigate()](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/Navigation/FrameFacade.cs#L197) method to navigate from one page to another page.

```
var parameter = pageNavInfo.QueryString;
return _frame.Navigate(
                  sourcePageType: pageNavInfo.View,
                  parameter: parameter,
                  infoOverride: infoOverride);
```

The `_frame` object actually is a general UWP built-in [Frame Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame) type. So, in general, the navigation parameters should be there when you call [_frame.GoBack()](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/Navigation/FrameFacade.cs#L68) to go back to the previous page.

But, if you add some breakpoints to debug it, you would see that the parameter's value always is `null` in the above `_frame.Navigate(sourcePageType: pageNavInfo.View,parameter:parameter,infoOverride: infoOverride);` code block. That's the reason why you always cannot get the navigation parameter when call `GoBack()` method. It's because it always passes the `null` as parameter to the `_frame.Navigate` method. It has implemented its own [NavigationParameters](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/Navigation/NavigationParameters.cs). All parameters that you passed to `_navigationService.NavigateAsync()` method should be in the '_external' parameters.

[image]

So, I've already told you the reason. I can't say it's by design or a potential issue. Maybe, they don't take into account the historical navigation parameters when calling 'GoBack()' method.You could submit your question to [Github issue](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues) to see if there're workarounds from the official. Or if you are interested in it, you could try to change its source code and compile your own custom version for you.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I've raised this over at [GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1728), amid some controversy the issue has been closed without resolution. 

I'm currently having some issues attempting to run the multitargeted Prism project on my dev machine, but I suspect as you point out I will end up Forking that repo and adjusting to suit our needs!

Comment: Can I ask what SDKs / NuGet packages were required to compile the Prism Library? Did you face any issues initially running the project? I'm facing issues getting this to even run and I'm not sure quite what I'm missing! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099085/unable-to-resolve-references-for-multitargeted-project

Comment: @Leigh I'm using visual studio 2017. My UWP project's target version is 17763. I download the whole Prism project and add the references to the relevant libraries directly. See [screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnG_EPB-ym9n9ibXq).

Comment: Prism v6 used to keep navigation parameters for forward navigation. If this is no longer the case in v7, then this needs further investigation. I will reopen the issue. @XavierXie-MSFT if you happen to be near campus in Redmond next week, we can catch up on your research, just ping me on twitter (see profile).